# Unable to show columns from 2 tables without creating loads of doubles

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So i'm a beginner at SQL server, this is actually a class so go easy on code for me :D

The question basically is: What do you write to show firstname and lastname on all cutomers that have made an order and also show the name on the pizza they've ordered.

There's 3 columns (Firstname, lastname is in the first table)

The pizzanames is in a other table.

If i select them all three and both tables it becomes a huge mess with showing all types of combinations.

The question does ask to show their fullname and the pizza they've ordered not all combinations, so exactly how do i do this?

Edit : i've tried inner join and selecting the columns + both tables

use napolipizza
select firstname, lastname, pizzaname
from customers, pizzatypes
go

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a join between the Customer table and the Pizza table. If you edit your question to include what you've tried so far, someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you would miss a third table where all orders are filled.

Something like

```
OrderID CustomerID  PizzaID
1       1           1
2       1           2
3       2           4
```

Then just use INNER JOIN on correct columns. You haven't posted your table structure, but it should look pretty much like this:

```
SELECT C.FirstName, C.LastName, P.PizzaName
FROM dbo.Orders AS I
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS C
    ON C.CustomerID = I.CustomerID
INNER JOIN dbo.Pizzas AS P
    ON P.PizzaID = I.PizzaID
```

Comment: The code i basically tried is use                                                             napolipizza
select Förnamn, Efternamn, namn
from kunder, Pizzatabell
go, i can't use enter on when responding for some reason, either way it creates all possible combinations, but i still don't understand how i'm meant to combine a customer order if...there's no order?

Comment: Aš i've said. You miss a third table, where you would store all orders. That's it. Otherwise joining doesn't make any sense at all. Ad in your example you would get all all possible combinations, that's it.